# Write generic function for either string or my custom type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have the following two extension methods. (I have a lot more, but I'll use these for this discussion.)

```
public static MyExtensions
{
    public static int IndexOf(this string s, Func<char, bool> predicate, int startIndex)
    {
        for (int i = startIndex; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (predicate(s[i]))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int IndexOf(this StringEditor s, Func<char, bool> predicate, int startIndex)
    {
        for (int i = startIndex; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (predicate(s[i]))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

They both do the same thing. One works with type `string`. And the other works with type `StringEditor`, which is a class I created.

My question is if anyone can think of a way to implement both in a single method using generics.

I cannot modify `string`, but I can make any changes needed to `StringEditor`.

I cannot derive `StringEditor` from `string` because `string` is sealed.

I couldn't find any interface implemented by `string` for accessing individual characters that I could implement in `StringEditor`. `IEnumerable<T>` is available but does not support accessing individual characters directly like an array.

And it isn't valid to make a type argument for both `string` and `StringEditor`.

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this T s, Func<char, bool> predicate, int startIndex) where T : string, StringEditor
```

I don't think this can be done. But maybe someone is more clever than me?

#### Update

Where I described that I needed to directly access individual characters, I meant using the `s[i]` syntax. In addition to generally being less performant, `IEnumerable<T>` does not support this.

While `IEnumerable<T>` could be used to perform the results of my two methods here, it does not allow direct character access.

Comment: How about a `Span<char>`? Whether this would work would depend on how `StringEditor` is implemented though.

Comment: I think the answer with `IEnumerable<char>` is good. You could also use `object` and a `ToString()` call which your class will need to override. But then it opens it up to all objects

Comment: @Sweeper: `StringEditor` allows modifying the string characters. It appears `Span<char>` does not support that. Also, if the user has a string then they'd have to convert it to a `Span<char>`. That's pretty efficient but would still add unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @djv: Yes, I understand. But I am intimately familiar with `IEnumerable<T>` and would have used it if it's appropriate for what I'm doing. Some methods depend on `s[i]` syntax as I've described. Also, I'm concerned about performance, and `IEnumerable<T>` will slow things down. Same thing with `object`.

Comment: "`IEnumerable<T>` will slow things down" Have you measured it or are you assuming it?

Comment: "That's pretty efficient but would still add unnecessary overhead." Again, same sentiment as @DStanley Have you measured it? Does that overhead actually matter? I really doubt it.

Comment: You could also put the logic of the algorithm in one method and write both signatures to call this method. Then the only duplication is in the signatures.

Comment: @Sweeper: There is definitely some code involved in producing a `Span<T>` from a `string`. My code works with potentially long strings. I want to maximize performance.

Comment: @djv: I don't know how you would do that without having the data converted to a common type, which would violate my goal of maximum performance.

Comment: @JonathanWood the thing is we don't know about your `StringEditor` implementation. Is there a backing field holding a string? Then just expose it

Comment: @djv: I'm not new to this. If there was a string property, yes I would expose this. I will tell you it does have a `char[]` property. I'm sure you would say just convert the string to a character array. But again, that doesn't equal maximum performance. Other than that, I can add anything I need to my class. But I want to do this directly without adding overhead.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [`__makeref`](https://benbowen.blog/post/fun_with_makeref/), which is an undocumented keyword that lets you reinterpret variables without copying anything, and just might allow you to do what you're asking. But honestly if performance is of the highest importance then the best solution is to use different overloads, as you have in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

Generics not needed. Use `IEnumerable<char>`, which is implemented by `String` and could be implemented by your `StringEditor`.

```
public static int IndexOf(this IEnumerable<char> s, Func<char, bool> predicate, int startIndex) 
{
    int i = startIndex;
    foreach (char c in s.Skip(startIndex))
    {
        if (predicate(c))
            return i;
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Or

```
public static int IndexOf(this IEnumerable<char> source, Func<char, bool> predicate, int startIndex) 
{
    var s = source.ToArray();
    for (int i = startIndex; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (predicate(s[i]))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not the functionality I need. I need to say `s[i]`.

Comment: I didn't see anything in your example that required `[]`, but if you really want random access you can always map the characters into a temporary array or list.

Comment: Oh I see. That is easily overcome.

Comment: I've got dozens of similar methods. Performance is important. So having to convert to an array or list every time I call these methods would be prohibitive. It's only worth doing if I can access the characters directly, as I'm doing. It would just be better if I could do it in a single method.

Comment: "I need to say `s[i]`" why? why can't you just add a function to `StringEditor` that enumerates the characters?

Comment: @DStanley: Because `IEnumerable<char>` doesn't support `s[i]` syntax. If you're suggestion that I should enumerable the array and then find the character at the given position every time I want to perform `s[i]`, I'll just repeat what I said elsewhere the performance is important.

Comment: I would measure the performance of using `foreach` and `Skip`/`Take` instead of `a[i]` - It's been a while, but my memory is that the iterator created over arrays was very efficient at returning the actual elements by index when using `Skip` and `Take`. You may find that the performance difference is negligible., Or just keep the code you have that takes different types, maybe factoring out as much as you can into common functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ReadOnlySpan<char>` as argument type.

```cs
public static int IndexOf(this ReadOnlySpan<char> s, Func<char, bool> predicate, int startIndex)
```

`ReadOnlySpan<T>` supports indexing. Since there's an implicit conversion from string to `ReadOnlySpan<char>` you don't even need to modify the call sites. And there's no measurable performance penalty with this conversion, since creating a Span is basically free, both in time as well as in memory usage.